# Using Hibernate to persist a List<Map<String, Object>>

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, persistence

I have the following Java Collection

```
List<Map<String, Object>>
```

I've written a custom converter class which can flatten this down to a List of `MyEntity` (where `MyEntity` is basically String, Value, Java type, parent collection) and re-assemble it back to a Map but I was wondering......

Is it possible to annotate the List such that Hibernate can persist a List of these Maps? I've had a brief look at the `collectionOfElements` annotation and I know there will be problems with the Object value due to Hibernate needed to convert to a valid database type.

Any ideas gratefully received :)

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to create a mapping for MyEntity?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I understand what you mean, `MyEntity` is mapped. I have a `List<MyEntity>` which is persisted. However, I have to do the conversion to and from this entity myself - i.e. I have transient methods which change the `List<Map<String, Object>>` to a `List<MyEntity>` on update and the other way on retrieve. I was hoping Hibernate could handle this conversion (much more reliably) for me.

Comment: I don't have a good answer, unfortunately.  What I usually do is make additional getters/setters on the POJO to make the conversion for clients that need that representation, which sounds like exactly what you're doing.